# Socket connection using utl_tcp

Tags: multithreading, sockets, plsql

How can i find the number of sockets open using utl_tcp.
Using below code i am able to get response form the server but  i want to use multithreading pls let me know if there is any tool or utility or how can i update my code to find how many threads are supported by the server on the port.

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE KLMestk11 IS
 bt_conn               utl_tcp.CONNECTION;
 retval                binary_integer;
 l_sequence            varchar2(250) := ' 1235kl5pl70406mnbv78000000013121310000051                000000850910334640000524126927082700000000009000000000000000000mkp29112013*TESTING                              *T000000000000057007760847T000000000000057007760847T0000000057007760847';
 l_sequence1           varchar2(250) := ' 1235kl5pl70406mnbv78000000013121310000052                000000850910334640000524126927082700000000009000000000000000000mkp29112013*TESTING                              *T000000000000057007760847T000000000000057007760847T0000000057007760847';
 l_sequence2           varchar2(250) := ' 1235kl5pl70406mnbv78000000013121310000053                000000970910334640000524126927082700000000009000000000000000000mkp29112013*TESTING                              *T000000000000057007760847T000000000000057007760847T0000000057007760847';
 l_sequence3           varchar2(250) := ' 1235kl5pl70406mnbv78000000013121310000054                000000850910334640000524126927082700000000009000000000000000000mkp29112013*TESTING                              *T000000000000057007760847T000000000000057007760847T0000000057007760847';
 l_sequence4           varchar2(250) := ' 1235kl5pl70406mnbv78000000013121310000055                000000850910334640000524126927082700000000009000000000000000000mkp29112013*TESTING                              *T000000000000057007760847T000000000000057007760847T0000000057007760847';
 s_time                TIMESTAMP;
 e_time                TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
 s_time := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
 dbms_output.put_line('Start Time:'||s_time);
 bt_conn := utl_tcp.open_connection(remote_host => '50.0.16.901'
                                   ,remote_port => 5423
                                   ,tx_timeout => 1
                                   );

 retval := utl_tcp.write_line(bt_conn,l_sequence);
 dbms_output.put_line(utl_tcp.get_line(bt_conn, TRUE));
 utl_tcp.FLUSH(bt_conn);
 utl_tcp.close_connection(bt_conn);

 bt_conn := utl_tcp.open_connection(remote_host => '50.0.16.901'
                                   ,remote_port => 5423
                                   ,tx_timeout => 1
                                   );
 retval := utl_tcp.write_line(bt_conn,l_sequence1);
 dbms_output.put_line(utl_tcp.get_line(bt_conn, TRUE));
 utl_tcp.FLUSH(bt_conn);
 utl_tcp.close_connection(bt_conn);

 bt_conn := utl_tcp.open_connection(remote_host => '50.0.16.901'
                                   ,remote_port => 5423
                                   ,tx_timeout => 1
                                   );
 retval := utl_tcp.write_line(bt_conn,l_sequence4);
 dbms_output.put_line(utl_tcp.get_line(bt_conn, TRUE));
 e_time := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
 dbms_output.put_line('End Time:'||e_time);
 dbms_output.put_line('Duration:'||timestamp_diff(s_time,e_time));
 utl_tcp.FLUSH(bt_conn);
 utl_tcp.close_connection(bt_conn);
EXCEPTION
 WHEN others THEN
  raise_application_error(-20101, sqlerrm);
  utl_tcp.close_connection(bt_conn);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on 16 connections in the utl_tcp package. Maybe some patch from Oracle that fix that.
See http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_30678_too_many_connections.htm

/Jörgen